# The Raabe test limit existence implies the sequence goes to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

> Let $b_n$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that the limit from the Raabe-Duhamel's test is positive, i.e. $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n\left( \frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}-1\right)=p > 0$$
> the limit exists and it has a positive value. Then $b_n$ must approach $0$.

My attempt:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there is $n_\varepsilon > 0$ such that for all $n > n_\varepsilon$ we have $p - \varepsilon < n\left(\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}-1\right) < p + \varepsilon \iff 1+\frac{p-\varepsilon}{n} < \frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}} < 1+\frac{p+\varepsilon}{n}$ i.e. $b_n$ is decreasing. Therefore, by the monotone convergence theorem, there exists $l \colon= \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$. Now $l$ cannot be $+\infty$ because the sequence is decreasing and $l ≥ 0$, because the sequence is assumed to be positive.

Assume $l > 0$, therefore take some number $e_1$ and there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > m$ we have that $l -e_1 < b_n < l + e_1$. Now using $\frac{p-\varepsilon}{n} < \frac{b_n-b_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}} < \frac{p+\varepsilon}{n} \iff \frac{b_{n+1}}{n}\left(p-\varepsilon\right) < b_n - b_{n+1}< \frac{b_{n+1}}{n} \left(p+\varepsilon\right)$ Now we sum this inequality from $n=m$ to $q$, where $q$ is a natural number. We get $$\left(p-\varepsilon\right) \sum_{n=m}^q\frac{b_{n+1}}{n} < b_m - b_q \implies \left(p-\varepsilon\right)(l-e_1)\sum_{n=m}^q\frac{1}{n} < b_m-b_q$$ If we let $q$ approach infinity, on the left hand side we have the Harmonic series which diverges to infinity, and on the right we have $b_m-l$ which is finite. Therefore $l=0$.

Is my proof corect? To me it seems like it is, but I couldn't prove by some squeezing of sequences that $b_n$ goes to $0$, I just proved it by contradiction. Is there a direct proof for this result?

Comment: How LHS is a harmonic series?

Comment: You need to specify $\epsilon<p$ to be decreasing, $e_1<l$, etc. otherwise the proof is fine. Another way is that $1/b_n>C \prod (1+(p/2)/n)> C p/2 \sum 1/n$

Comment: Why $1/b_n$ is greater than a constant times a product? Shouldn't there be a sum?